# ROLES dinâmicas com Spring Security?

Tags: spring, spring-security

Tenho um sistema onde todos que acessam tem uma ROLE padrão user, mas se for designado para um usuario uma tarefa do tipo secretário, a ROLE desse usuário será SECRETARIO, usuarios podem designar tarefas e mediante isso quem receber a tarefa terá sua ROLE modificada. Um outro "problema" é que um usuario pode participar de mais de uma tarefa, acumulando funções diferentes. Alguém já fez parecido com esse caso?

Comment: A resposta te ajudou? Precisa de alguma informação adicional? Considera aceitá-la?

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa ter uma tabela de permissões para ser usada pelo Spring Security, conforme simplificado o exemplo abaixo:

#### Usuário

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String login;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "user_authority",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "authority_name", referencedColumnName = "name")})
    private Set<Authority> authorities = new HashSet<>();

    // Getters and Settes
}
```

#### Autoridade

```
@Entity
public class Authority implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    // Getters and Settes

}
```